# Ektron CMS , metadata date format

Tags: ektron

I've recently migrated my Ektron installation (8.01 SP1) to a new server which had the regional settings as US (ran the installers, moved database and restored).

I changed the region to UK and restored the database (a backup from a server which was region UK).

However when a user selects a date (say publication date metadata) using the date picker , it's displayed as UK but saved in US format.

What configuration change do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the issue. I looked at which users were running the Ektron services (local user) and SQL Express (Network services).

I then applied the UK regional settings to the system accounts by following these instructions
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-vista/apply-regional-and-language-settings-to-reserved-accounts

Did a reboot and the dates are in the correct format.